# How to diagnose/repair SSD causing BSOD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod

Extensive troubleshooting pinpointed my [SSD](https://amzn.to/3kZNXSc) to be the culprit of intermittent B(lue)SODs; no crashes since replacing. Problem is, the new (old) one is much weaker, and I need the faulty but better SSD.

No troubleshooter identified SSD as the culprit; I only found out after switching to Linux, and the installer informed the SSD may be faulty. My Windows fails to generate crash dumps, and Event Viewer would show seemingly unrelated driver errors. This said, if I were to swap the SSD back in, I wouldn't know where to begin looking for a fix, or whether there is one.

How can I debug a BSOD-ing SSD, and potentially repair it? Paid software is fine, but must explicitly address BSOD, as SSD otherwise works fine (no overheating, good write lifetime, read/write speed, etc).

---

**SMART** scan results; further info [here](https://superuser.com/q/1570125/1010638)

[image]

Comment: Please post the SMART data of the disk. If you lack a product for that, for example use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy).

Comment: How old is the failing SSD? They don't last forever, and will eventually begin to fail to read and write. Check the SMART status of the drive. There are apps to check SMART for Linux and Windows. SMART errors will show you if a drive is beginning to show signs of failure. SSDs are really cheap to replace these days.

Comment: @harrymc Done  .

Comment: Not a scan please, the attributes and values.

Comment: I would start recording the error information shown in the BSOD error page. If your PC auto reboots this can be disabled in settings.

Comment: @harrymc The what? The specs should be [here](https://amzn.to/3kZNXSc), but if it's something from a scan I'd need to swap in the SSD first (which I can do, but unsure what exact info you're asking).

Comment: @Robert [Did it](https://superuser.com/q/1570125/1010638), also had SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION, and 1 or 2 others, and I addressed all but 2 Event Viewer errors which then narrowed down the BSOD to only CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED, I think. I found many possible fixes online for [this error](https://superuser.com/q/1570125/1010638), tried a few, none worked, then just replaced SSD.

Comment: I meant SMART attributes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02SFk.png).

Comment: If you replaced the SSD, then we're finished here?

Comment: @harrymc Replaced to an older and weaker version; I seek to diagnose/repair the better one if possible. I figured some may suggest software like [HD Sentinel](https://www.hdsentinel.com/), which I'm unsure can aid with BSODs.